# How to display posts from specific category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys I have a code which rendered 5 recent posts from a specific category. Here is that

```
    function postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            }
            }
    } else {
    // no posts found
}
$string .= '</ul>';

return $string;
```

What i wated is that above code display recent posts from specific category from 1 to 5 but i want to display recent posts from 2 to 6. For better understadings focus on this e.g.
Suppose i have a category named Pizza and in that category I have 10 posts named 
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
Post 5
Post 6 
Post 7
Post 8
Post 9
Post 10
So if I apply above code to my homepage it will display post from category Pizza are
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
Post 5
but i want this
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
Post 5
Post 6

Yes i want that code to start showing posts from 2 not from 1. So how to do this.
Please help me I am not a web developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a counter ($i) in the loop and pull the first 6 posts, skipping the first one using the counter to check.

```
function postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); 

$i=1;
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    if($i>1){
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $string .= '<li>';
        $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        } else { 
        // if no featured image is found
        $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        }
        }
        ++$i;
        }
} else {
// no posts found
}
$string .= '</ul>';

return $string;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Funk Doc I am not a developer so can you do this for me what you write above please.

Comment: The posted code in the answer will work as you requested.